# Slim3 use reference is wrong

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, classloader, slim-3

I'm tring to prepare a simple empty application with Slim3 and composer.

This is my front controller:

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';


    $config=[];
    $config['displayErrorDetails'] = true;
    $config['addContentLengthHeader'] = false;
    $app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);

    foreach(glob("../app/dependencies/*.php") as $dependency){
        $dependency=include $dependency;
        $dependency($app);
    }
    foreach(glob("../app/middleware/*.php") as $middleware){
        $middleware=include $middleware;
        $middleware($app);
    }
    foreach(glob("../app/routes/*.php") as $route){
        $route=include $route;
        $route($app);
    }

    $app->run();
```

And this is the unique route file I have:

```
<?php 

return function (\Slim\App $app){
    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello");
        return $response;
    });
};
```

When I run the application I got an error:

> Argument 1 passed to Closure::{closure}() must be an instance of
>   Request, instance of Slim\Http\Request given

I must add this "uses" to my route file:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
```

Why php is taking the wrong (Slim) class for request and response?
Really I have to prefix them for each controller file?

Answer (score 0):

> Really I have to prefix them for each controller file?

Yes. `use` declarations are per file as [documented in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will *NOT* inherit the parent file's importing rules.

---

You might or might not be able to leave out the type in front of the parameter. Whether you are able to do so depends on whether Slim uses Reflection to determine whether to put the `$request` and `$response` object. Based off the error message you get I suppose you are able to simply remove the type.